# Rails: Run a script after loading a library with async: true

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So let's say I want to load the following library asynchronously:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js", async:true %>
```

Now, I want to run the following code **after loading the library**:

```
<script>
  $('#business_name').autocomplete({ source: '/businesses_finder' });
</script>
```

**How is this done?**

It would be really cool if I could call a function following async loading.. Like:

```
async:true, callback_function: 'autocomplete'

function autocomplete() { 
  $('#business_name').autocomplete({ source: '/businesses_finder' });
}
```

Comment: This comment seems helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699135/what-exactly-is-the-benefit-of-the-html5-async-attribute-on-script-elements#comment42425945_17699411 I'm not proficient enough in javascript yet to know how to translate that comment to code though.